# Convert specific date format in the ending day of previous month in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format

I have the following table format

```
 Date1     | Date2     | other columns
 12FEB2019 | 12OCT2020 | ...
 19FEB2019 | 08NOV2021 | ...
 ...       | ...       | ...
```

I want to convert it into

```
 Date1     | Date2     | other columns
 31JAN2019 | 30SEP2020 | ...
 31JAN2019 | 31OCT2021 | ...
 ...       | ...       | ...
```

Here is what I tried for Date1 (and similarly for Date2) until now:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import MonthEnd
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date1) - MonthEnd(1)
```

However, the results have a different format (e.g. 2020-09-30 instead of 30SEP2020), not what I expected
What should I add to my code in order to get the desired format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing date logic,  convert it back to a string using `strftime()`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Date1     | Date2     | other columns
 12FEB2019 | 12OCT2020 | ...
 19FEB2019 | 08NOV2021 | ..."""), sep="|")
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]


df.assign(**{c:(pd.to_datetime(df[c]) - pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(1)).dt.strftime("%d%b%Y").str.upper()
 for c in df.columns if c.startswith("Date")})
```

|  | Date1 | Date2 | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 31JAN2019 | 30SEP2020 | ... |
| 1 | 31JAN2019 | 31OCT2021 | ... |

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already accepted another answer before seeing yours.

Comment: if you feel this is the better answer you can change which answer you accept

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [strftime documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#examples-of-usage-date).

Here is an example

```
date = pd.to_datetime("31JAN2019")
date.strftime("%d%b%Y")
>> 31Jan2019
```

You could use the .upper() method for strings to get the output in all caps.

In your example you could apply the above as such:

```
df['Date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date1) - MonthEnd(1)
df['Date1'] = df['Date1'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d%b%Y").upper())
```

Comment: Thanks. However, your code gives me the error 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: Ahh, I only used it for a date object. You should then use the .apply() method. I can update my example.

Comment: Well, strftime can be used, but (pd.to_datetime(df.Date1) - MonthEnd(1)) should be replaced with (pd.to_datetime(df.Date1) - MonthEnd(1)).dt
Another option is to use apply, indeed. 
(pd.to_datetime(df.Date1) - MonthEnd(1)).apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d%b%Y").upper())